# No overload for 'insert_method_here' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#, error-handling, suppression, keyeventargs

I am trying to build a program that has a button, and everytime that button is clicked, it moves the button and adds to the score. However, I am trying to disable the Enter key, or suppress the command when pressed. Here is what I have so far

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, KeyEventArgs k)
    {
        if (k.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            k.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
        score = score + 10;
        timesClicked++;
        int rand1 = RandomNumber(1, 400);
        int rand2 = RandomNumber(1, 400);
        button1.Location = new Point(rand1, rand2);
        toolStripScore.Text = ("Your score is " + score);
        toolStripClicks.Text = ("You've clicked the button{0} times " + timesClicked);
        winCheck();
    }
```

This is what I added to prevent the enter key from going in.

```
if (k.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) { k.SuppressKeyPress = true; }
```

However it generates the error... "No overload for 'button1_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'" And when clicked to show the location, it opens the code for Form1.Designer and points to this this line. "this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);"

Any help on resolving this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method signature does not match `EventHandler` delegate (that is, you cannot just add `KeyEventArgs` argument and get this working). You'll need to handle more than one event to do what you want (look at `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` events).

Alternatively, use `MouseClick` event instead of `Click` event.

Comment: I've tried putting both 

 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)

and 

private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)

With the if statement in the program and neither of the things prevent the enter key from working.

Comment: @Cistorian try `MouseClick` event then, it should ignore enter key by design

Comment: What do you mean try MouseClick? Try it with what?

Comment: try `MouseClick` instead of `Click`

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think that the issue is in your decleration of `button1_click()`.

An event handler can only have the signature of

```
delegate void EventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

So, take the Key press out of `button1_click`, and put it in a `KeyPress` event.

Answer (score 0):

EventHandle delegate, is two parameters, not three.
and your method has three parameters, so it's wrong.

see:[EventHandler delegate information in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(VS.71).aspx)

first, your have to modify your method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

and then judge the type in the method like this:

```
KeyEventArgs k = null;
if(e is KeyEventArgs){
    k = (KeyEventArgs) e;
    //do sth here about pressing 'enter'
}
```

delegate ,method must have the same parameters, the same return type, or it will be exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The EventHandler delegate is a template.

*public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, TEventArgs e);*

So if you change the line:

> this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

to:

> this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

it should work.